# Complie error: Argument Not optional

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using the below code to change Date format. using this macro as a dropdown option in ribbon using XML. but it's giving "Argument Not optional" error.

Please help where I am doing wrong.

```
    Public Sub ConvertDateFormat1(control As IRibbonControl)
'
' date formating (MM/DD/YYYY)
'

Dim oCl As Word.Cell
Dim oRng As Range
'
' Condition to check the selected data

'
  If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Or _
      Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    MsgBox "Select a cell or range of cells before running" _
      & " this macro.", , "Nothing Selected"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  For Each oCl In Selection.Cells
    Set oRng = oCl.Range
    '

    'Drop of the end of cell mark
    '
    oRng.End = oRng.End - 1
    With oRng
      If IsDate(oRng) Then
         oRng.Text = Format(oRng.Text, "MM/DD/YYYY")

    Else ' not a date - end loop
        MsgBox ("Invalid Date Format")
    End If
    End With
  Next oCl
lbl_Exit:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

as per its *signature* your sub would expect a `control` argument of type `IRibbonControl`

but since it actually doesn't use it, you may want to remove it:

```
Public Sub ConvertDateFormat1()
  ' rest of your sub code as it is
```

Comment: @PankajKumar, did you get through it?